# Unable to trigger re-authentication with firebase v4, javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was previously able to trigger `onAuthStateChanged` without needing to sign user out after they verified their email using these methods called one after another.

```
firebase.auth.currentUser.reload()
firebase.auth.currentUser.getToken(true)
```

I updated them to `getIdToken`

```
firebase.auth.currentUser.reload()
firebase.auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true)
```

However with v4 of firebase previous and new approach are not re-triggering `onAuthStateChange` anymore. Is there a way to still achieve it now? i.e. for sign up flow where user doesn't need to log out -> signs up -> verifies email -> clicks "Continue" button that calls 2 functions above -> `onAuthStateChanged` get's triggered with user email now being verified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In version 2.x of Firebase Authentication, the auth state changed handler was only invoked when the user's authentication state changed. So when they signed in or out.

In version 3.x of the Firebase Authentication SDK, the same callback was also invoked for token refreshes. But this lead to developers having problems efficiently updating their UI, since this callback would be invoked even when the authentication state didn't change (even though the token did).

That's why this behavior has indeed changed in v4: the `onAuthStateChanged` doesn't fire anymore for token refreshes. There is a separate `onIdTokenChanged()` method that *does* fire in that case: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onIdTokenChanged

From there:

> Adds an observer for changes to the signed-in user's ID token, which includes sign-in, sign-out, and token refresh events. This method has the same behavior as `firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged` had prior to 4.0.0.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(function(user) {
>   if (user) {
>     // User is signed in or token was refreshed.
>   }
> });
> ```

Comment: Ah I see, interesting, but I assume `onIdTokenChanged ` will trigger whenever firebase refreshes user's token as well?

Comment: To add to above, i.e. user is in the middle of the round of playing a game and token refresh happens, I assume this function will be triggered without user reload?

Comment: @Ilja: yes, `onIdTokenChanged` should fire when the DB refreshes the token. From the reference docs it seems that `onIdTokenChanged` literally has the behavior that `onAuthStateChanged` used to have. I didn't test that myself though.