# Firebase 4.1.3: onAuthStateChange not called after first sign in with email and password

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I upgraded the version of Firebase for my app from 3.5.0 to 4.1.3 and noticed that the onAuthStateChange callback function is no longer called after a user successfully signs in for the first time after verifying their email address.

The app is written in JavaScript.

These are the relevant sections of my code:

**Callback setup**

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChange);
```

**Callback**

```
function onAuthStateChange (user) {
    console.log(user); // Not appearing in console
}
```

**Sign in**

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function (user) {
        console.log("signInWithEmailAndPassword success"); // This appears in the console
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("signInWithEmailAndPassword", error);
        self.signInError = error.message;
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.$apply();
        });
    });
```

**Edit** - these are the steps to reproduce the problem (the typical action of a user of my app):

- User downloads and launches app
- User registers with email and password
- App sends email verification email
- User receives verification email and clicks on link
- User goes to sign in page of app
- User signs in triggering the console.log("signInWithEmailAndPassword success");
- onAuthStateChanged callback **is not** called

For development and testing purposes (not what a user would do but I have done)

- User reloads the app
- User is now in the app
- User signs out of the app
- User signs in to the app triggering the console.log("signInWithEmailAndPassword success");
- onAuthStateChanged callback **is** called

Comment: That's weird. The `onAuthStateChange` should be called whenever auth state changes, so when the user signs in. Please share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Since you have the problem in JavaScript, a small jsbin would be ideal.

Comment: My initial guess is that your user state does not really change, since they were already signed in. In that case, the 4.x SDK does indeed not call `onAuthStateChanged` anymore. If you need to detect this, listen for the new `addIdTokenListener`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#addIdTokenListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.IdTokenListener)

Comment: Also see my previous answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039314/unable-to-trger-re-authentication-with-firebase-v4-javascript/45039388#45039388

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - I've just confirmed that 3.5.0 works as expected. It is weird.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - I've also just confirmed with 4.1.3 that it only happens at the first sign in after verifying the email address. "Refreshing" the app puts the user in the app. Signing out and signing in again calls `onAuthStateChange`.

Comment: Hey @camden_kid, can you clarify, is the user already signed in? and you are signing in again on the same page? if the user is not already signed in, he/she will trigger onAuthStateChanged on initial sign-in. It shouldn't matter whether that user's email is verified or not.

Comment: @bojeil As mentioned in the question. The user is not already signed in. It's when they first try to sign in.

Comment: I signed up with an email and password. I then sent email verification and signed out. I verified the email by clicking the link. I returned to my test app, reloaded the page and signed in with the same email and password. The onAuthStateChanged listener triggered as expected. If this are not the steps to reproduce this issue, please provide them.

Comment: @bojeil Those aren't exactly the same steps. I don't understand "I then sent email verification and signed out". Also, "reloaded the page". That's not the action of a typical user for my app, or any other app I would have thought. Thanks for trying to replicate the problem. I will update my question with my steps.

Comment: Ok, i looked at your steps. Please correct me if i am wrong. On the same page you call createUserWithEmailAndPassword, the user is verified and then the user signInWithEmailAndPassword on the same page. This will not trigger an onAuthStateChanged listener as createUserWithEmailAndPassword also signs in the user and you are signing in with the same user. Internally as the user id has not changed, the state change listener will not trigger.

Comment: But it gets triggered with version 3.5.0. `createUserWithEmailAndPassword ` doesn't sign in the user. It creates the user. There's a difference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword() does in fact log in a type of user in.

You will find that if you type

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  console.log("onAuthStateChanged()");
```

that createUserWithEmailAndPassword() does trigger the console log. However, there seems to be no valid "user" object, which would explain why nothing appears for you since you are only logging the user.

I ran into the exact same problems. At the sendEmailverification() step notice how it does require you to use auth().currentUser, signalling there must be some sort of user signed in (I am not sure how firebase handles the difference between email verified users and non-verified users behind the scenes)

You can simply called the signOut() function after sending the email verification and it should allow the onAuthStateChanged() function to call when logging in for the first time (without reloading the app)

```
  firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Email verification sent");
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
      console.log("Signed out!");
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error signing out!", err);
    });
```

It is rather confusing that you can actually "Log in" successfully without causing a change in AuthStateChanged or returning any errors.

TLDR: Remember to use the auth().signOut() function after sending the email verification.

Comment: +1 I've had this issue again and using signOut helps. However, I don't think it is ideal and requires some extra code to handle the change in auth status.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way, i hope it'll work

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
console.log(user);
})
```